# Position Chart relative (over or under) another chart in VBA

Tags: vba, charts, position

I have a sheet with an chart in it. I am using another sub to create another chart, and would like to place it UNDER the first chart.

I know how to set the position of a chart using .Top or .Left, but don't know how to retrieve the position of the first chart. Any suggestions?

I tried:

> Activesheet.ChartObjects(2).Top = Activesheet.ChartObjects(1).Top

--> This works just fine, but the charts are overlapped. I need to replace the last ".Top" with ".Bottom", but ".Bottom" is not accepted (In fact, optimally, I would like to place at the bottom of the first chart with a little gap).

Sounds easy, but can't quite do it!

Thanks,
Al

Comment: There's no such thing as `.Bottom`, but this can be easily computed from `.Top + .Height`, or if you would like a gap, `.Top + .Height + 4` (for example)

Comment: Thank you very much Alain. This seems to work (although I am not sure on what scale the number 4 is measured. When I tried 10 instead, the chart was created in the same position).

Comment: Ok, just figured it out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim C1CO As ChartObject, C2CO As ChartObject

    Set C1CO = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    Set C2CO = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2")

    With C2CO
        .Top = C1CO.Top + C1CO.Height + 10
        .Left = C1CO.Left
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Siddarth. That seems to work. Any idea what scale is the number after C1CO.Height measured? When I tried 8 instead (I needed a smaller gap), it was generated in the same position